# Auto refresh a page with count down time

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, timer, updatepanel

I have a small C# code behind to refresh a webform page (form.aspx) after 15 seconds as below:

```
lblMessage.Text = "<b><h2>Thank you!</h2></b></br>We will be right with you.<br><br><br>(This page will be refreshed automatically after 15 seconds)";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Success!", "setInterval(function(){location.href='/form.aspx';},15000);", true);
```

Right now the page will be refreshed after 15 seconds. How do I also make the timer count down every second? i.e., 15 => 14 => 13 => ... 1 then refresh so it will be better for users, they will know what is going on with the page...

Comment: Create an input or element on the page, that shows the timer counting down on each interval.

Comment: I think this would be better suited and easier to understand putting it in your aspx rather than code behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"<b><h2>Thank you!</h2></b></br>We will be right with you.<br><br><br>(This page will be refreshed automatically after <span id='counter'>15</span> seconds)"

ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Success!", "setTimeout(function(){location.href='/form.aspx';},15000); counter = 15; setInterval(function(){counter--; document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = counter;},1000);", true);
```

Should do it.

If added a `span` with `id` `counter` around the refresh message number.

Then I added `counter = 15;` to initialize a default value of 15. And another `setInterval` to the script block firing every second. With each pass it subtracts one from `counter` and updates the `span` with the new counter value. Users should now see the page counting down. I also changed the first `setInterval` to `setTimout`, since it's technically a timeout and not an interval that should occur every 15 seconds.

Comment: Absolutely genius! I was about to add UpdatePanel, Timer, ScriptManager and all kind of controls ... into the aspx page but this works very well and simple.

Comment: Can I ask you one more favor, right now I am displaying a clock (Hour: Minute + Date) on the aspx page using updatepanel and timer, it causes server side post back every 30 seconds which not a good thing, how can I do it using javascript, something simple as your answer, can you add it to your answer.

Comment: @RonaldinhoLearnCoding please start a new question or chat for this and provide me with some code.

Answer (score 6):

In javascript I would go with something like this.

```
<div id='countdown'></div.

var countDown = 15;

function countdown() {
    setInterval(function () {
        if (countDown == 0) {
            return;
        }
        countDown--;
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = countDown;
        return countDown;
    }, 1000);
}

countdown();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chzzcosy/

Comment: thanks for this very clean code and also a working demo, this works perfectly!